# Multiple Labels on X coordinate when using symbolic coordinate

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using pgfplots to plot bar charts; when I try to use symbolic labelling for the x coordinates, I get the labels repeating. Any ideas why, the snippet is below.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel={Trace-sets},
ylabel={Number of Reference Points},
enlargelimits=0.15,
symbolic x coords={1, 2, 3},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
anchor=north,
legend columns=-1},
ybar=5pt,
bar width=9pt,
nodes near coords,
grid=major
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,166) (2,612) (3,130)};
\addplot coordinates {(1,60) (2,612) (3,46)};
\legend{Offline, Online}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Number of reference points at which Signal Strengths were sampled}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: add `xtick=data` otherwise additional ticks are added but since you don't have enough tick labels it's repeated for the missing ones.